# While updating data in Firebase, error is "can't set header" in my NodeJs server

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase database for storing data. If i update data first time it work fine , but if do update second time it give error.
Code for updating data is.

```
    router.post("/saveSetting", function(req, res) {
    var fbref = firebase.database().ref("setting");
    fbref.set(req.body).then(function(data) {
    res.end('ok');
       });

    })
/*get data from firebase*/
  router.get('/setting', function(req, res) {

  var fbref = firebase.database().ref("setting");
  fbref.once("value").then(function(data) {
    res.send(data.val());
    })
  });
```

[Terminal ScreenShoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V58Sg.png)

Comment: You posted a link to a picture of error messages. Please replace this with the actual text of the error messages, so that they become searchable and are immediately readable. We'll also need the [minimal, **complete** code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The snippet you shared now uses `req`, but doesn't declare it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , I uploaded my code. problem occur when i am doing post request to server, i disable my save button till my request is got complete.

Comment: You're sending data to the `res` response object after calling `end()` on it. If you search for the error message, you'll probably get a lot of hits explaining why this is and how to prevent it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, Can you give some reference for updating my data for my node server.      thanks

Comment: Problem POST request, If i change it to GET , there were no issue. it was working fine.

Comment: Previously programming was calling POST call two or more times so it was giving problem.

Answer (score 1):

firebase is completely made on socket. If you are listening using **on()**,then you have to deregister your listener after event got fire. or you could simply use **once()** listener.

This issue arises when you try to send the same response to the client on second time.